# is it bad to have many different measurements for the same target variable?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering, data-science-model

I'm working on a dataset that has repeated measurements for the same target variable.

When I don't change anything and create model, cross validation overfits with 0.99 score but in testset it gives around 0.39.

When I use mean, std, skew, quartiles for each measurement to have only one measurement for each feature, it gives a much better score.

Can anyone explain to me why? and when it is good to use the second method?

the original dataset looks like this (all numbers are fake):

```
id /measurement1/measurement2/.../target/
0-1/0.18283     /0.12855     /.../  1   /
0-2/0.1141      /0.38484     /.../  1   /
0-3/0.4475      /0.18374     /.../  1   /
```

and transformed dataset looks like this:

```
id /meas1_avg/meas1_std/meas1_skew/meas2_avg/meas2_std/.../target/
0  /0.28747  /0.183848/ 0.198384  /0.18484  /0.28474  /.../  1   /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are solving two different problems here.

In the first problem, you want to predict the target variable given **one** noisy measurement.

In the second problem, you want to predict the target variable given some statistics from **a group** of noisy measurements.

Your results show that the second problem is easier to solve which is intuitive, since the amount of noise (variance) for average of multiple measurements is less than only one measurement (closely related to [Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)), thus the relation in the second problem is easier to find by the model.

Therefore, if both problems are equivalent to you, go with the second problem which is easier to solve.